# Unity VR Max File Size

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus, quests

I have recently run into errors when building my Unity VR app for the Meta Quest 2 - and I wanted to check my understanding of something - from everything I've found it sounds like there is a max file size for an apk build of 2gb, and maybe the max theoretical is 4gb - but I am wondering if that is true?

Mainly because it seems mad to me! My Quest 2 GPU/CPU is perfectly capable of rendering and playing my 1.5gb scene in isolation, but when I add the menu and other scenes it becomes too big - so the answer would seem to be to scale back on the size of the level, texture optimisations,etc - but it seems crazy to me that that is enforcing a limit beyond the hardware? Ie - the GPU/CPU is capable of playing much more complex scenes that are going to look smaller and more rubbish because of an arbitrary max file size to a single file apk. It seems like limiting the hardware for no reason.

In addition - I am working for the Quest 2 - and have been reading articles on how the Quest 3 means apps are going to be bigger and it has all this fancy new hardware - but are they not going to be limited by the same 2 or 4gb limit?

I feel like I am missing something here - either that games can be bigger and there is a workaround I haven't found? Or maybe there is a hardware reason for this limit that I don't understand?

I feel like it would blow my mind if every app on the Quest store is less than 2gb?

Any help at understanding it or possible solutions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I answered about the file limitation. But re-reading your question, it seems like you might also be asking something to the effect of "how can I keep my app playable when I add menus & multiple scenes?" If that's something you're having trouble with, I suggest adding that as its own question.

Comment: If one scene is over 1GB, it might be a good idea to go through the build log and make sure there aren't any uncompressed textures or other files wasting space. For example, if you had a regular texture that was 1024*1025, it wouldn't get compressed because 1025 is not a power of 2. This can easily cause texture that should only be a few MB to swell to 30MB or larger.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [VRC.Quest.Packaging.5 docs](https://developer.oculus.com/resources/vrc-quest-packaging-5/)

> **Criteria**
>
> APK files must be less than 1 GB in size, but can be accompanied by multiple expansion files up to 4 GB each.

So yes, technically all of the apps are limited to 1 GB (and therefore less than the 2 GB limit you asked about). But it's possible to technically exceed that restriction by using expansion files.

The docs include links to [Unity asset files to manage download size](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/ps-assets/) (OBB expansion files & required asset files).