# Building Android .aab from Unity

Tags: unity, android

I have a VR game developed in Unity for Oculus and I want to create an Android App Bundle to upload it to the play store as a mobile game too. When I go into build I select this options: [image: Building options]

And here is the problem, after finishing compiling it throws some errors:

1.

```
OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException (System.Boolean overflow, System.String overflowResourceKey) (at <a40b0ad4a868437393ad434631fb6ff1>:0)
System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles styles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at <a40b0ad4a868437393ad434631fb6ff1>:0)
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at <a40b0ad4a868437393ad434631fb6ff1>:0)
System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value) (at <a40b0ad4a868437393ad434631fb6ff1>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.BundleToolWrapper.CheckApksSize (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String stagingArea, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c8df8c387877487dae452aacc833e6ce>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.CheckApksSize.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8df8c387877487dae452aacc833e6ce>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c8df8c387877487dae452aacc833e6ce>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <c8df8c387877487dae452aacc833e6ce>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <c8df8c387877487dae452aacc833e6ce>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

2. 

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 294 seconds (293528 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&
```

3. 

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <5092d70d16a64dd9a555dd50f38aead0>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

The strange thing for me is that the .apk compiles just fine. I need the aab because the game is now around 2GB and will likely be more in the future. Where does this error come from? is it a code problem or something related to configurations?

Comment: "The game is now around 2GB", so something just a little over 2,147,483,647 bytes? That's the largest number that can be stored in a signed 32-bit integer, which is what this build process is trying to parse the size into. It overflows that integer's max and fails, as we can see in the first stack trace. [You may want to check out this recent answer about dealing with APK file size limits for VR development for the Oculus Quest](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/207688/39518)

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you, I think it still does not solve all my problems but it is the answer to my question so i will ask another one if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DMGregory said, the problem is that the aab file is larger than a 32-bit singed integer. The problem in this case is that I had a scene which weighted over 2GB.
The other problem I had is that the first scene was to big, it has to be under 15MB, a loading scene, the other can be bigger, but not more than 2GB and the aab has a maximum size but I do not know what that limit is.